# Pass an action as a reference

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to set an Action inside another Action, but the Action I pass to it is still null in the end. Here's a dumbed down example:

```
Action<Action<VerifylocalResult>> docollectprint = (vl) =>
{
    vl = (vlocres) => 
                    {
                        //DoStuff
                    };

    //This returns false, indicating the action has been set:
    Console.WriteLine((vl == null).ToString()); 
};

//Hookups
docollectprint(vlocobj.Action_NotExists);

//This returns true, so the action has not been set:
Console.WriteLine((vlocobj.Action_NotExists==null).ToString());
```

I already tried passing a getter method instead of the real deal but the result is the same.. it's still null in the end.

```
Action<Func<Action<VerifylocalResult>>> docollectprint = (vl) =>
        {
            Action<VerifylocalResult> theaction = vl();
            theaction = (vlocres) => 
                {
                    //DoStuff
                };

            //This returns false, indicating the action has been set
            Console.WriteLine((theaction == null).ToString());
    };

//Hookups
docollectprint(() => { return vlocobj.Action_NotExists; });

    //This returns true, so the action has not been set
Console.WriteLine((vlocobj.Action_NotExists==null).ToString());
```

Is there any way to do this? Also, sorry if this has been asked before, but when I searched all I found was people trying to do `Action<ref string x>` or something similar.

*Update (solution):*

```
Func<string, Action<VerifylocalResult>> docollectprint = (msg) =>
            {
        Action<VerifylocalResult> vl = (vlocres) => 
        {
            /*DoStuff*/
        };
                    return vl;
            };

    //Hookups
    vlocobj.Action_NotExists = docollectprint("x");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References are passed by value by default. This means that any changes to a reference are scoped locally only. You should be returning something rather than attempting to alter a passed in reference. From MSDN:

- A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the
  delegate that references it goes out of scope.
- Variables introduced within a lambda expression are not visible in
  the outer method.
- A lambda expression cannot directly capture a ref [ByRef in VB] or
  out parameter from an enclosing method.
- A return statement in a lambda expression does not cause the
  enclosing method to return.
- A lambda expression cannot contain a goto statement, break statement,
  or continue statement whose target is outside the body or     in the
  body of a contained anonymous function.

Comment: I see, thanks! I changed the Action to a Func and had it return the Action<VerifylocalResult>. That should work.. can't accept your answer yet though... too soon ^^ And thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 3):

Let's get rid of all the actions, and try the same example with a more mundane object. Your code is basically equivalent with:

```
Action<string> changeString = (s) =>
    {
        s = "result";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    };
```

string myString = "someString"
   changeString(myString); //the reference is passed by value and won't work
   changeString("someString"); //What should this do???

However, you could just return the changed thing, or in this case, just return the thing, as you are not doing anything with the value it's passed, along the line of:

```
Func<string> getString = () => return "result";

string myString = "someString";

myString = getString(); //works
```

or in your case:

```
Func<Action<VerifylocalResult>> docollectprint = () =>
    {
        return (vlocres) => 
        {
            //DoStuff
        };
    };

vlocobj.Action_NotExists = docollectprint();
```

Comment: Like I said it's a dumbed down example so don't read too much into the actual code, it's irrelevant. The Func<> thing was correct though but someone beat you to it ;D

Comment: Yeah, but it was a fun answer to write, so I'll leave it in :)

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you can use another delegate. First, declare it:

```
delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T reference);
```

Then change your method to this.

```
RefAction<Action<string>> docollectprint = (ref Action<string> vl) =>
{
    vl = vlocres =>
    {
        //DoStuff
    };
    //Action has been set
    Console.WriteLine((vl == null).ToString());
};

Action<string> action = null;
docollectprint(ref action);
//Action is still set
Console.WriteLine((action == null).ToString());
```

This, of course, in case you don't want to use `Func` for whatever reason.

Comment: I tried it and it works just fine. Might come in handy sometime, thanks ;D

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want a `Func<Action<VerifyLocalResult>>`:

```
Func<Action<VerifylocalResult>> docollectprint = (vl) =>
{
    vl = (vlocres) => 
    {
        //DoStuff
    };
    return vl;
};
```

then you can do

```
vlocobj.Action_NotExists = docollectprint();
```

Comment: Yeah figured it out shortly after Jeff's anwer.. thanks though ;D By the way, the `vl` in your answer has to be removed for it to work, since that Func doesn't take any paramters.